# UIView animateKeyframes not working with NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to animate a UIView by reducing it's width constraint, but it doesn't works well when using `UIView.animateKeyFrames`. Here is my code :

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0/2.0, animations: {
            self.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0 // works well
        })

       self.titleSquareHeightConstraint?.constant = 20 // previously 170
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/2.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/2.0, animations: {
            self.titleSquare.layoutIfNeeded() // instantaneously jump to 20
        })

    }, completion:nil)
```

The titleSquare's height will jump from 170 to 20 instantaneously. *Note: titleSquare is a UIView*. Also, I used to work with `UIView.animate` and the code below works just fine :

```
    self.titleSquareHeightConstraint?.constant = 20
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 1,
                   options: .curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {

                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // Perfectly works

    },completion: nil)
```

What am I doing wrong with my `UIView.animateKeyframes` method? It seems I don't get completely how it works?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try changing the constraint out side the closure before the start of the animation block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely obvious or intuitive, but...

You want to tell the **view** to `layoutIfNeeded()`:

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1.0/2.0, animations: {
            self.titleLabel.alpha = 0.0 // works well
        })

        self.titleSquareHeightConstraint.constant = 20 // previously 170

        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1.0/2.0, relativeDuration: 1.0/2.0, animations: {

            // tell self.view to layout, not the titleSquare view
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        })

    }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Aww, that was just it... Thank you. feel a bit dummy right now